# Agora Video & Voice call not working giving error Access denied finding property

Tags: agora.io

**

```
Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
```

**

getting this error in every time in real device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask